# Как очистить кэш у пользователей моего сайта

Tags: javascript, html, кэширование

Внес изменения на сайт, а картинки остались старые. Я понимаю, что если почищу кэш у себя, то все будет в порядке. Как быть с пользователями? Я же не могу на их компьютере почистить кэш. Прочитал про мета тег `cache-control: no-cache` - тоже не очень подходит, так как по сути перегружать сайт, тогда как изменения вносятся всего в одну директорию - как-то неразумно. Можно ли очищать кэш конкретно для этой директории: `pta-ua.com/img/champ/champ.jpg`? Эта картинка меняется раз в неделю, названия остается то же самое.

Comment: `cache-control: no-cache` вполне можно повесить на одну лишь картинку, копайте настройки вашего веб-сервера

Answer (score 2):

В ссылке на ваше изображение можно использовать случайный параметр, например такой:

```
a href="/img/champ/champ.jpg?v=22"
img src="/img/champ/champ.jpg?v=22"
```

где `22` - случайная строка, может быть любой. В данном случае - это номер недели. Так как вам нужно обновлять картинку каждую неделю - этот номер можно раз в неделю накручивать на единичку вверх. Или считать динамично на сервере.

Comment: А в этом случае браузер будет подменять старые картинки или копить все варианты?

Comment: Если уже залазить в файл index, то проще назвать картинку по другому и указать другой путь.

Comment: Что я, собственно, и сделал)

Comment: @КулагаИлья , будете каждую неделю переименовывать?